# Why is くなかった wrong and ではありません preferred in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, jlpt, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

I was taking a n5 grammar test and I came across the question:

> あの人{ひと} は有名{ゆうめい}　＿＿＿＿

The answer I chose was くなかった. However, the quiz said the correct answer was ではありません. Why is that?

Comment: hint: There are two types of adjectives in japanese...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

有名 is a *na*-adjective and thus is followed by だ・で・な・に (or by じゃ < では)

> あの人は有名だ
> *lit.* that person is famous
>
> あの人は有名な人だ
> *lit.* that person is a famous person
>
> あの人はきっと有名になる
> *lit.* that person is surely going to become famous

You can think of ではありません or じゃありません as the negative of です (which in turn is the polite form of だ whose negative would be ではない or じゃない). Hence

> あの人は有名**ではありません**
> *lit.* that person **is not** famous

The point of the question seems to be to test your ability in identifying *i*- and *na*-adjectives correctly as well as inflecting these adjectives. One cheap way of recognizing *i*-adjectives is by their dictionary form, which always ends in an *okurigana* い (like 速い、寒い、安い、…). Here 有名 does **not** inflect like an *i*-adjective. Of course, *i*-adjectives would inflect like

> あの人は速**くなかった**
> *lit.* that person **was not** fast

where くなかった is the ending you chose. Here 速い *hayai* means "fast" (note the い as *okurigana*).